# How to select the total count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables (postgresql)

tableA

```
a b
----------
1 A
2 B
```

table B

```
c b
----------
1 A
3 B
```

I want to find out the same number of columns `b`, but if column `a` and column `c` are the same, count one.
So the final result should be

```
b count
----------
A 1
B 2
```

How should I write sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `union all` for the 2 tables and then `group by b` to count distinct values of `a`:

```
select t.b, count(distinct t.a) counter
from (select * from tablea union all select * from tableb) t
group by t.b
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate by column `b` and take the distinct count of column `a`:

```
SELECT b, COUNT(DISTINCT a) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY b;
```